# Group by query not using index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

This is my query -

```
select bill, render, count (*)
from dx
group by bill, render
```

This is the index I created for it -

```
CREATE INDEX bill_render ON dx (bill, render);
```

Why is my query not using the index with and without the count(*)?

```
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=70441673.89..89334654.09 
   rows=61437331 width=27)"
    "  Group Key: bill, render"
    "  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=70441673.89..87798720.82 rows=122874662 width=27)"
    "        Workers Planned: 2"
    "        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  
    (cost=70440673.86..73614935.97 rows=61437331 width=27)"
        "              Group Key: bill, render"
    "              ->  Sort  (cost=70440673.86..71080646.06 rows=255988880 width=19)"
    "                    Sort Key: bill, render"
    "                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on dx (cost=0.00..18940581.80 rows=255988880 width=19)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that it cannot perform an index only scan, and a normal index scan (that has to fetch the table rows to check for visibility) would be slower than a sequential scan.

If you want to get an index only scan in PostgreSQL, you have to make sure that most table blocks are marked “all-visible” in the *visibility map*. Then PostgreSQL can skip the expensive heap fetch.

The visibility map is maintained by `VACUUM`, so run that on the table to improve the performance.

Comment: If after running `VACUUM`, it was still not using the index, would it be better to use the plan it suggested or keep trying to get it to use the index?

Comment: You said the performance was better after `VACUUM`, was it not?